# Changing select's option display style to none under MSIE

Tags: html, css

Could someone please give me a clue as to why the following code does not work under MSIE?

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="si">
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
<option value="">3</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var e=document.getElementById("si");
e.size=3;
e[0].style.display="none"; // <-------- no effect
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE doesn't allow you to manipulate `option` elements directly. In my experience, you need to remove all of the `option` elements from the `select` and repopulate them with whatever changes you want to make already applied (in this case, one element removed).

Comment: Follow up: this approach is still required for IE11 and Safari 8.  (Possibly Opera as well, but I didn't test that one.)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having to deal with hiding option elements in those versions affected, I posted a workaround here which doesn't clone or remove the options but wraps spans around them, which is arguably much easier to deal with:

http://work.arounds.org/issue/96/option-elements-do-not-hide-in-IE/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok under MSIE, with hopefully no "side effects", if you find something wrong please let me know it, thanks.

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="si">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var e=document.getElementById("si");
e.size=3;
var a = new Array();
var n = new Array();
var x = 2;
if(!a.length)for(var i=0,m=e.length;i<m;i++) {
    a.push(e[i].value);
}
while(e.firstChild)
    e.removeChild(e.firstChild);
for(var i=0,m=a.length;i<m;i++) {
    if(x==a[i]) {
        e.add(new Option(a[i],a[i]));
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```