# display = 'none' works in Mozilla but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Applied style=“display:none” in <option> not working in IE but working Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187300/applied-style-displaynone-in-option-not-working-in-ie-but-working-mozilla)

I have a JS that is supposed to search in a list and show only the results and hide the others and for some reason my code works only in Mozilla, any ideas how to make it work in Chrome and IE?

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function searchit1() {
                        arrayAdmins = document.getElementById
                        var keyword = document.getElementById('searchbar1').value;
                        var xx = document.getElementById('allUsers');
                        var xy = document.getElementById('selectedUsers');
                        var selectedAdmins = [];
                        i = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
                            if (xx.getElementsByTagName('option')[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                                xx.getElementsByTagName('option')[i].style.display = 'block';

                            }
                            else {
                                xx.getElementsByTagName('option')[i].style.display = 'none';

                            }
                        }
                        var j = xy.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < xy.length; i++) {
                            if (xy.getElementsByTagName('option')[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                                xy.getElementsByTagName('option')[i].style.display = 'block';

                            }
                            else {
                                xy.getElementsByTagName('option')[i].style.display = 'none';

                            }
                        }
                    }

                </script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can we see some HTML? I'm in chrome right now and if you open the console on this very page and type: `document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.display = 'none';` the title of this page will disappear.

Comment: Have you made sure that your `getElementsByTagName[i]` in chrome is returning a HTML Element?

Comment: The first line in the function has an unclosed getElementById with no parameters, and that's a syntax error!

Comment: @adeneo no it's not. `arrayAdmins = document.getElementById` without the parens merely sets the (in this case global) variable to the function. This means you can do `arrayAdmins('h1')`. Probably not what the OP intended, but surely not a syntax error

Comment: @tkone - Oh yeah, you're right, that would just reference the function. Still a weird thing to do, atleast calling it `arrayAdmins` ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo

Answer (score 2):

Styling of form controls is not consistent across browsers and operating systems. Firefox will allow you to show/hide `<option>` elements by manipulating their `display` property, but Chrome won't. I'm not sure about IE.

The safest way to go about this is to have a complete list of options somewhere (an array of values or objects), and add/remove elements from the `<select>` as needed, based on that list.

Comment: Is there a justification for this behavior?

Comment: @fastreload that's something you'd have to ask either the Chrome or WebKit teams probably :)

Comment: Yeah, I actually meant that =). I meant do you know any links in documentations which explains the reason behind this decision. Well, I think google is my friend =)

Comment: I'm not sure if this still stands, but browsers used to use operating system calls to render some form elements. In this case, they're not like regular elements which are created/controlled by the browser, so you can't style them.

Comment: But, I can definitely add/remove them

Comment: @fastreload Yes, you can, the problem is just with styling them.

Comment: so basically I have to rewrite the lists or do you know any other method to hide the elements in the list? I have tried to use visibility hidden but it just hides the element it does not delete the empty rows and I can't use removeChild because it's supposed to be a live search

Comment: Yes, you have to rewrite. And I don't see why you can't use removeChild (although it may be simpler to just clear all options and re-add the relevant ones). Maybe you could use some existing autocomplete script instead?