# jQuery get Value of option in Select Menu

Tags: jquery

I want to find all options of a select menu that has a value of "undefined", and then hide them.

Here is my jSFiddle if that helps.

```
<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1"><option>Navigation</option><option value="http://example.com/">Home</option><option value="undefined">Philosophy</option><option value="http://example.com/shop/">Shop</option><option value="undefined">Winemakers</option><option value="undefined">- Czech Republic</option><option </select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/huwrowlands/6SDWY/

Comment: what do you mean by "hide?"

Answer (score 0):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/38NSL/

Basically:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('option').each(function(e)
    {
        if($(this).val() == "undefined")
        {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#tinynav1 option[value="undefined"]').remove(); - By @jahuna

Comment: Actually that's my answer >.> Juhana only noted `hide` doesn't work (but it does, only not in IE).

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#tinynav1 option[value="undefined"]').hide();
```

Apparently IE doesn't respect `display` properties on option elements. In that case you can just use `remove()` instead of `hide()` *or* suggestions found in [Applied style="display:none" in <option> not working in IE but working Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187300/applied-style-displaynone-in-option-not-working-in-ie-but-working-mozilla) and [Changing select's option display style to none under MSIE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225021/changing-selects-option-display-style-to-none-under-msie).

Comment: @HuwRowlands select jquery version from the top left dropdowns.

Comment: @HuwRowlands You need to include the JQuery library in the fiddle... See http://jsfiddle.net/6SDWY/5/

Comment: `.hide()` won't work for options. You need to `.remove()` them.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana - Worked a treat!